# Some files created years into the future in NFS mount to AWS EFS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, nfs, encrypting-file-system

We just saw a couple files get created years into the future on an EFS volume over an NFS mount from a Linux EC2 instance.

The "Change" time is correct, but the Access and Modify are years out.

Has anyone else experienced this?

```
$ stat input-f65bf618-82d7-4e8c-a472-3ce063dd17e9.xml
File: 'input-f65bf618-82d7-4e8c-a472-3ce063dd17e9.xml'
Size: 0             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 regular empty file
Device: 28h/40d    Inode: 5601753348689698754  Links: 1
Access: (0000/----------)  Uid: ( 2999/  thomascat)   Gid: ( 2999/  thomascat)
Access: 2032-11-03 13:29:20.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2035-07-10 03:09:25.000000000 -0500
Change: 2018-08-29 15:21:16.585000000 -0500
Birth: -

$ stat input-cef401e8-d84d-4da7-8700-c5f468044c1e.xml
File: 'input-cef401e8-d84d-4da7-8700-c5f468044c1e.xml'
Size: 0             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 regular empty file
Device: 28h/40d    Inode: 14389560454087948323  Links: 1
Access: (0000/----------)  Uid: ( 2999/  thomascat)   Gid: ( 2999/  thomascat)
Access: 2033-05-03 02:08:48.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2021-11-11 15:25:56.000000000 -0600 
Change: 2018-06-20 15:56:18.535000000 -0500
Birth: -
```

Weird.

Comment: Is that metadata controlled by EFS or can it be set by your application? How were the files created?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that whatever created the files had a wrong system time. Or they were unpacked from some archive and had a wrong timestamp in there. I doubt it's EFS's fault - EFS only stores what you tell it to store.

Comment: The system mounting the volume has NTP and files are created at a rate of about 20 files per minute.    The ones that get future-ized are nestled right among files that reflect a sane timestamp.